# How can I use React Native as frontend and CodeIgniter 3 as a backend?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, codeigniter-3

I have Program in Codeigniter 3 i would like to extend it version in React Native but i couldn't find any hooks or code connect them each other if its possible can anyone show an example with code of login or something to connect them together in an efficient way. please?

Would like to an example program connecting each other(RN and Ci)

Comment: Actually im using codeigniter 3 and is there any way that shows an example with that with react native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use codeigniter as an REST API layer. You can use the following package to create REST server with codeigniter.
[codeigniter-restserver](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver)

And, then use react/ react-native to consume those APIs.

Hope that answers your question.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much brother let me try it.

Comment: Actually im using codeigniter 3 and is there any way that shows an example with that with react native

Comment: i once created a scaffold for myself based on `codeigniter` & `react`. Here is the link: https://github.com/mkdudeja/codeigniter-react-template. React native should also follow the same pattern.